# How to write a complex installer script for a component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, installation

I would like to ask the user some questions in a dialog way during installation of my component. As far as I know, this could be done in the preflight method. But I am not sure how to do user interaction there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the Joomla documentation for the installer script? https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the documentation. So far, I have created the update functionality in the script.php file. The update-function is relatiely huge since this is a migration script to use joomla's category system for my own component. However, it would be great if I could provide the user with some feedback during installation "steps". If that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if user action via the preflight method in script.php during installation is possible. I have never seen that before. I have seen an extension using the postflight used to display a license key input form.